# problems with css on MacOs, on windows in all browsers is OK

Tags: css

I have problem with positioning my div. On Windows each browser is ok, but on MacOS it's different. This is the site: http://www.pulbus.pl

The problem is in the home page and in the contact page. The div with contact in the lower-left corner is below the blue label. It's lower than in windows about 20px.

This is my doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

My xhtml and css is valid, I've checked them on w3 validator.

Code:

```
<div id="data">
    <span id="name">Pul-Bus Grzegorz Pulcyn</span> <br/>
    ul. Waleniowa 7/3 <br/>
    85-435 Bydgoszcz <br/>
    <a href=" mailto: kontakt@pulbus.pl">kontakt@pulbus.pl</a><br/><br/>
    <span id="tel">tel: +48 500 100 333</div>
</div>

#data
{
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #003664;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    width: 320px;
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    top: -380px;
    right: 160px;
}
```

Comment: what browser are you using on Mac, and what version? Also do you have a snippet of code?

Comment: @theraven, +1, @rafal, you need to show us some code. Are you using a doctype? Which one? At the least I'd suggest showing us the source of the page, or a link to a live demo-page that exhibits the same problem.

Comment: is your markup shown above a direct copy and paste?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are missing an end tag

```
<div id="data">
    <span id="name">Pul-Bus Grzegorz Pulcyn</span> <br/>
    ul. Waleniowa 7/3 <br/>
    85-435 Bydgoszcz <br/>
    <a href=" mailto: kontakt@pulbus.pl">kontakt@pulbus.pl</a><br/><br/>
    <span id="tel">tel: +48 500 100 333</span>
</div>
```

the `</span>` after the tele number is missing in your example markup

Answer (score 0):

on windows I have tested my site on: chrome, opera, ie, firefox
on Mac: ff i safari

It is really strange, maybe some font issues or sth like that? it is possible?
i don't have snippset now, this is only a div with span inside with position relative set up.

Comment: To expand on your question, and to provide further information, you'd do better to hit the 'edit' link below the question and add to the question, rather than offering comments as 'answers.' :)

Comment: And please provide a link or some screenshots to the actual problem.

Comment: As well as the version of the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

In FF 3.5 @ MAC, you must set...

```
#data { top: -101px; }
```

...to display correctly.

Also...

```
#readmore { top: 8px; }
```

...will correct another bad positioning.

I must say that construct a website relative/absolute positioning is a big headache to mantain. I suggest switch to a *static floated structure* in a *box model hack*.

Anyway, I recommend you the JavaScript Library [CSS Browser Selector](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/) to apply in an easy-timeless way the css hacks you need in this way:

```
.os.browser .your-markup { ... }
.mac.ff3_5 #data { top: -101px; }
```

Hope this helps. :)